# Why won't my 2D data points in Matlab connect to become lines?

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, 2d, line

My code creates three "lines" of of data points, but won't connect the points into lines! I've looked at the tutorials, and tried things like plot(Time, CurrentSpeed1, '--') and adding markers, but no matter what, its always three different coloured series of points that aren't connected. Here's what I got:

```
Time = 0;

while (Acceleration1 > 0.012 || Acceleration2 > 0.012 || Acceleration3 > 0.012)
    Drag = (1/2) * AirDensity * (CurrentSpeed1^2) * DragCoefficient * Area;
    Force = EnginePower/CurrentSpeed1;
    Acceleration1 = (Force-Drag)/EmptyWeight;
    CurrentSpeed1 = CurrentSpeed1 + Acceleration1;

    Drag = (1/2) * AirDensity * (CurrentSpeed2^2) * DragCoefficient * Area;
    Force = EnginePower/CurrentSpeed2;
    Acceleration2 = (Force-Drag)/HalfWeight;
    CurrentSpeed2 = CurrentSpeed2 + Acceleration2;    

    Drag = (1/2) * AirDensity * (CurrentSpeed3^2) * DragCoefficient * Area;
    Force = EnginePower/CurrentSpeed3;
    Acceleration3 = (Force-Drag)/FullWeight;
    CurrentSpeed3 = CurrentSpeed3 + Acceleration3;

    plot(Time, CurrentSpeed1, Time, CurrentSpeed2, Time, CurrentSpeed3);

    Time = Time + 1;
    hold on
end

xlabel('Time (Seconds)');
ylabel('Speed (m/s)');
hold off
```

Why oh why? Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @shoelzer said, you need an array of values. Here's a simplified version of your code to show an example:

```
Time = 0;
CurrentSpeed1=0;
CurrentSpeed2=0;
CurrentSpeed3=0;
while (Time<10)
    OldTime=Time;
    Time = Time + 1;

    OldSpeed1=CurrentSpeed1;
    CurrentSpeed1 = Time+1;

    OldSpeed2=CurrentSpeed2;
    CurrentSpeed2 = Time+2;    

    OldSpeed3=CurrentSpeed2;
    CurrentSpeed3 = Time+3;


    plot([OldTime Time], [OldSpeed1 CurrentSpeed1], [OldTime Time], [OldSpeed2 CurrentSpeed2], [OldTime Time], [OldSpeed3 CurrentSpeed3]);

    hold on
end

xlabel('Time (Seconds)');
ylabel('Speed (m/s)');
hold off
```

I just make sure to store the 'old' points and then i can connect them with the new points

Comment: So..hang on...what is OldTime? And where are the arrays?

Comment: In order to connect two points via a line, you need to provide the plot command the x and y values of the two points in vector form (ie: `plot([xpt1 xpt2],[ypt1 ypt2]);`). What I'm doing with 'OldTime', 'OldSpeed1', etc. is storing the previous xy values of your points so that i can pass both the old coordinates and new coordinates into the plot command. this will connect your two points

Comment: storing each value in an array like @shoelzer said is another way to do the same thing; instead of plotting it in steps within the loop, you plot the whole thing afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Your time and speed variables are single values so when you plot you get points. To plot a line, you need an array of values. Example:

```
figure
hold all
plot(3, 4, 'o') % plot a point
plot(1:10, 1:10) % plot a line
```

Inside the loop you need to store the calculated values in arrays, then plot the arrays after the loop.

Comment: So.... After each paragraph, i'll need something like:
`array1.append(CurrentSpeed);
array2.append(CurrentSpeed);
array3.append(CurrentSpeed);`

And then after the while loop:
plot(Time, array1, Time, array2, Time, array3)?

Comment: Pretty much. In Matlab you would do `array1[n] = CurrentSpeed;`. Be sure to [preallocate](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-18150/) or it can get very slow with large arrays.